# Android AlarmManager interval fluctuates

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using an AlarmManager with an interval of 5 minutes, and I have made some tests for a few days and it seems that the interval of the AlarmManager isn't constant all the time, but it changes some times. This is causing my app not to work as it sould.

Why is this happening? Is there a solution?

The code I am using is:

```java
iHeartBeatService = new Intent(SpyMe.context, HeartBeat.class);
piHeartBeatService = PendingIntent.getService(SpyMe.context, 101010, iHeartBeatService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000, piHeartBeatService);
```

on a Samsung Galaxy 3 I5800 with Android 2.2

Comment: Post the code you're using to create the alarm.

Comment: @Zosimas : You will not get a constant time interval for your `alarm`, even if you use `RTC_WAKEUP`. I have also experienced this. I am using `Samsung Galaxy Ace`. I had set the interval to 2 minutes, but the actual interval varied from 2 min to 2.5 minutes.

Comment: It's even worse. I have put it to 3 minutes and it seems that it goes over 5 minutes sometimes! How to make a serious application with a non serious OS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your code for us to help you. I'm going to shoot in the dark here and guess that you're not using RTC_WAKEUP for your alarm.

```
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calander.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```